# Regular expression woes C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am having issues when attempting to use the following regular expression:

```
string profileConfig = File.ReadAllText(str);

string startIndex = "user_pref(\"network.proxy.autoconfig_url\", \"";
string endIndex = "\"";

var regex = startIndex + "(.*)" + endIndex;
// Here we call Regex.Match.
Match match = Regex.Match(profileConfig, 
                          regex,
                          RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
{
    // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    MessageBox.Show(key);
}
```

I get the error:

> Additional information: parsing
>   "user_pref("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "(.*)"" - Not enough )'s.

Is my regular expression malformed in some way?

Comment: ( is a sepcial character in regex, you should look at escaping it in your startIndex string.

Comment: You should probably replace '.' by '\.'. 

The '.' character will catch any character. I think you want to catch the '.' only.

Comment: Because regular expressions have a very sensitive structure, I'd consider it good practice readability-and-maintainability-wise using a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), so as to get less confused between string escaping and regex escaping.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape the first bracket if it is your intention to match the character `(` literally:

```
string startIndex = "user_pref\\(\"network.proxy.autoconfig_url\", \"";
```

Comment: You need to escape the escape: `"user_pref\\(\"network.proxy.autoconfig_url\",` (use two \\), otherwise the C# compiler will think it is an escape sequence it is suppose to handle, not an escape for the regex.

Comment: Rather then escape yourself, try using Regex.Escape(startIndex).

Answer (score 0):

Correct this:

```
"user_pref(\"network. -> "user_pref\(\"network.
                                   ^
```